# What damage can police cause during a search?

Tags: california, police, search-and-seizure

Consider the following hypothetical: police in California raid a home (with a warrant) to search for drugs.

The home in question has a security system in place which includes CCTV cameras. Wanting to avoid being filmed, the police disable the cameras.

Can they legally do this? Does it matter whether they cause permanent damage, such as spraying over lenses or removing components?

Jurisdiction is California.

Comment: What police can and cannot do depends on the jurisdiction, which you did not state. This sounds more like a specific complaint than a question within the scope of this site.

Comment: It is a specific complaint , but none the less is it legal to maliciously destroy property

Comment: @KenChampaign I don't have time to write out a full answer right now but [this would probably be what I base my answer on](https://www.npr.org/2019/10/30/774788611/police-owe-nothing-to-man-whose-home-they-blew-up-appeals-court-says)

Comment: @User37849012643 I don't think that case is very relevant. There the policew were trying to efect an arrest of a person who posed an immediate danger to others. Quite different from the situation supposed by the question.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Discretion given to the police to execute their duties are far and wide. I don't see the difference between the police damaging property while arresting someone or while executing a search warrant and I think if you look into the case law you'll see the same thing.

Comment: Surely you can perform a search without spraying paint on any camera lenses. I very much suspect that would be illegal. End you can find the names of the perpetrator, because whatever evidence is found during a search can't be used without someone saying in court that they found the evidence. On the other hand, it's reasonable to think that drugs might be hidden in your sofa cushions, so they might be cut open without any comeback for you.

Comment: See the answers to [Are there any remedies for abusive or insulting behaviour by agents executing a search warrant?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/134/are-there-any-remedies-for-abusive-or-insulting-behavior-by-agents-executing-a-s/201)

Answer (score 2):

Police have qualified immunity from lawsuit when acting in their official capacity in a discretionary act. But this is not absolute immunity, see [Pierson v. Ray](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/386/547/), 386 U.S. 547, which held that there is immunity good faith official actions of police who have not been "put on notice" that a certain action is in fact illegal. As announced in [Harlow v. Fitzgerald](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/457/800/), 457 U.S. 800, "government officials performing discretionary functions, generally are shielded from liability for civil damages insofar as their conduct does not violate clearly established statutory or constitutional rights of which a reasonable person would have known". There is a fair amount of clear evidence that a person has the right to film police in public, and no question that they have the right to film on their own property so it is unlikely that the court would rule that wanton destruction of cameras to prevent legal filming was a "newly discovered wrong": the police *should* know that such an act has already been deemed illegal ([Glik v. Cunniffe](https://casetext.com/case/glik-v-cunniffe), 655 F.3d 78).

Comment: Some funny arguments by police in Glik v. Cunniffe: If you tell the police "I'm recording you" they can't arrest you. So the police claimed that when Glik pointed his phone at them openly, they couldn't know he was actually recording, so it was a secret recording, so they could arrest him. But then if he _wasn't_ recording they shouldn't have arrested him? So if I witness police violence, my phone's battery is empty, and I pretend to record them to make them stop using illegal violence, they basically say they can arrest me for recording, because I didn't. What nonsense.